# Paragraph numbers and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I have given a number to some of the paragraphs of my PhD dissertation. But they appear as a `\paragraph` in the table of contents. I also have "real" `\paragraph` titles, that I want them to appear in the table of contents.

For the moment, if the "false" paragraphs are `\paragraph*`, the don't appear in the table of contents but they don't number those paragraphs anymore. If they are `\paragraph`, they do number the paragraphs, but they appear, as single number, in the table of contents.

Basically, I would like them to appear in the text, but not in the table of contents.

If you have ideas, thanks a lot!

A compilable example, with `\paragraph`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand*{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}.}
\newcommand\p{\paragraph{}}
```

^This is the `\paragraph` I'm talking about.

```
\begin{document}

\section*{\noun{\textemdash{} }Section 1 \textemdash \noun{}\protect \\
\noun{Lorem impsum}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Section 1 --- Lorem ipsum}

\selectlanguage{english}%
\p{}\foreignlanguage{french}{XXXXXXXX}

\selectlanguage{french}%

\subsection*{§1 \textemdash{} Ipsum lorem}

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{}§1 --- Ipsum lorem}

\selectlanguage{english}%
\p{}\foreignlanguage{french}{XXXXXXXXX}

\tableofcontents{}

\end{document}
```

What it is now:
[image: What it is now]
What I would like it to be, without losing the numbers in front of the paragraphs in the text:
[image: What I would like it to be]

Comment: Please provide a real MWE! This is a lot of code to read. I guess such a question could be asked with 5 lines of code. `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\tableofcontents\paragraph{test}\end{document}`. Your question is very unclear as it is. Where is the `\paragraph` you are talking about?

Comment: I just did it. Is it ok?

Comment: Better, but not compilable. What is `\noun` coming from? Do we need all these language switches and so on? Wouldn't it make more sense, to put those "paragraphs" in a `enumerate` environment? And I do not understand your macro `\p`. You can't give your paragraph a title. And you can not make it starred.

Comment: I tried to put them in an enumerate environment, but I don't want all paragraphs to have a number. The macro \p allows me to choose what paragraph has a number.

Comment: Basically, I would like to decide what paragraph is in my table of contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I must say that your MWE is not easy to understand. I just ditched all that code you have there for sections and for French and English.  Here is a very simple approach for having some paragraphs appear in the TOC and others not:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\newcommand\simpleparagraph[1]{%
  \stepcounter{paragraph}\paragraph*{\theparagraph\quad{}#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\simpleparagraph{normal} paragraph (not in the toc)
\paragraph{special} paragraph that will appear in the toc.
\simpleparagraph{normal} paragraph (not in the toc)
\paragraph{special} paragraph that will appear in the toc.
\end{document}
```

[image: enter image description]

If you make a lot of changes to the layout of sections and the like I recommend the [titlesec](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package.

If this is not what you are looking for I also have to ask you to clean up your MWE to be *minimal*.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! Sorry for the poor MWE. I will do better next time.